# Android SDK update fails, saying-> XML verification failed for http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, debian

Am new to Java and Android. I am trying to install Android SDK on Debian Squeeze. I have just downloaded and setup the SDK. When I try to update the packages list I get following error.

```
XML verification failed for http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml.
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I have checked the force https to use http and this is the only error I see. Am I missing something?

I just checked my java version

```
kumar@gentlehow-lx:/$ java --version
java version "1.5.0"
gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.4.5
...
```

I tried to do a sudo update and the packages were not updated.

I fixed this by manually downloading the XML and then from XML I figured out which zip file I needed. After downloading the file I simply extracted the file and moved the extracted folder to SDK/platforms folders. The API was visible in in Installed components.

Comment: Have you tried looking at that url in your browser?  Does it display correctly?

Comment: yes, I can download the XML on http and https

Comment: It's true, from time to time I'm experiencing similar things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that this seems to be an issue with the java-gcj.

Once I installed the oracle java and stopped using java-gcj the error went away.

You can grab the oracle java here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Also, after installing oracle java and when using Fedora I had to issue the following two commands to get the oracle java to be the default:

```
sudo alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_25/bin/java 20000
sudo alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_25/bin/javaws 20000
```

After installation, running 'java -version' should give you a simliar output to verify it installed correctly:

```
java version "1.6.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
```

Re-run the android tools and everything should work.

Comment: I gotta agree with you, I also used `galternatives` to change my gcj to oracale/sun-java, I am going to choose your answer as a solution so that this question is closed :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this: find the file androidtool.cfg and add the following line:

```
sdkman.force.http=true
```

and try again.

Comment: I have already checked the force https to use http and I checked the flag is true for root and my user account.